# Post-hoc chi-squared multiple comparison tests using complex samples module in SPSS v. 20

Tags: spss, chi-squared-test, post-hoc

This questions refers to computing cross-tabulations and chi-squared tests of independence through the SPSS complex samples module available in SPSS versions 19 and up. I am able to compute the overall chi-squared through the test of independence option, but I'd like to compute post-hoc tests of independence between all cells.

Does anyone know if this is even possible (i.e., post-hoc tests of independence through the complex samples module of SPSS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSTABULATE command in the CS module to get the population proportion and standard error estimates. Use these to complete proportion tests either manually or in excel

Comment: This is in fact what we ended up doing. Thanks for the reply jake.